# Как добавить новости на активити, не изменяя приложение через интернет?

Tags: android, android-studio

Хотел создать новостное андроид-приложение для своего города.
Как добавить новости на активити, не изменяя прилоение через интернет?

Comment: Уточните вопрос. Вы хотите узнать как готовое приложение может обновлять свои данные беря их с сайта?

Comment: Уточняю: Хотел создать Новостное андройд приложение. Хочу добавить новости через интернет. Типа такой. ФОТО: http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/photo/40928699.cms

Comment: Что-то как то не очень с уточнением. Вам нужно в какое то существующее приложение добавить отображение своих новостей или в ваше собственное приложение добавить каким либо способом новости не используя интернет? Напишите подробно что у вас есть и что вы от этого хотите.

Comment: У меня есть простой андройд приложение. С контентом который был добавлен при созданий приложений. И я хочу ежедневно обновить этот контент. Как новостные приложений. В общем хочу превратить простое приложение обратить в Новостн.прил.

Comment: Вот например этот американское приложение (фото: http://android-apps.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/07/fox-news-android-app-1.png) как то добавит каждый час новости. Через интернет. Я тоже хочу добавить новости через интернет. Но не могу понятие как это сделать...

Comment: Ну вам нужен сервер который будет отдавать новости по запросу и приложение которое будет запрашивать у вашего сервера новости. Примеры взаимодействия с сервером на андройде можно легко загуглить и сделать по аналогии, но написание сервера вещь достаточно серьезная и вот так просто сесть и написать его неподготовленному человеку не получится.